# C# webbrowser postData -> default

Tags: c#, browser, postdata

I have a problem sending postData while user click on button on some webpage. It means that postData cannot be Null. Here is the code:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(e.Url, "_self", default(byte[]), headers);
```

As you can see I've used default(byte[]) for postData overload, but this is not working.
What I'm trying to do is NOT to change post data, just headers.

Edit:
I do this like this:

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
                .
                .
                .    
                webBrowser1.Navigate(e.Url, "_self", default(byte[], headers);

                .
                .
                . 
        }
```

When the browser is navigating I add headers. This works, but when user press on some button or writes username and password into login forum and press submit, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass empty byte array. default of array is null, because arrays are reference type.

Comment: You are still using default. Did you read my advice carefully?

Comment: OK, sorry, but how do you mean empty byte array? I've tried it like this, but it's not working: byte[] postdata = new byte[900]; and then webBrowser1.Navigate(e.Url, "_self", postdata, headers);

Comment: I think Tomas means a byte array of zero length, as in `new byte[0]`